# Razor page background image not displaying

Tags: css, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to add a background Image for a single Razor Page. Below is what I have tried with no success. The page only returns the text with no background image.
[image]

My CSS page

[image]

Here is my razor page calling the css. What am i missing?
[image]

Comment: What does your inspector tell you? Any unresolved images? Is the css loaded and can you see the background image being declared?

Comment: Maybe your server is case sensitive? Try `background-image: url("../images/DKBFSAndy.PNG");`?

Comment: @Jackdaw Im not sure what happened to your answer you but that seemed to of resolved it. I'll give the credit but i don't see the answer for some reason. Maybe something was cached up?

Comment: @Andy Williams: My solution was for ASP.NET Framework. But I am not sure that it will work in ASP.NET Core. If you found some solution post your answer instead. :)

Comment: Please don't use screenshots to capture code. Instead paste it as text, and format it as code using markdown. If you need to call out specific lines, you can use inline comments or break up the code into multiple blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code,you didn't add content to div,or set the size of the div,so the div height is 0px like the following:
[image]
So you cannot see the background.If you want to show the background,here is two solutions:

1.set size of div:

css:

```
body,html {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  height:100%;
}
.bgAboutMe {
    background-image:url('../images/Peppa.jpg');
    height:100%;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat
}
```

view:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/background.css" />
    <div class="bgAboutMe" style="width:300px;height:100px">
    </div>
```

result:
[image]

2.add content to it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/background.css" />
<div class="bgAboutMe">
    <h1>Here is content</h1>
    <h2>Here is content</h2>
    <h3>Here is content</h3>
    <h4>Here is content</h4>
</div>
```

result:
[image]